# Mathematical Method of Geometric Second Quantization?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, banach-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

I have recently been studying the method of geometric quantization, and I noticed a few methods in it that seem like they could be used to create a geometric second quantization (specifically of the gauge fields). The paper I'm following (titled *Geometric Quantization*, written by Andrea Carosso) seems to provide a method of such a process on bosonic Fock states, however, I am wondering about the following method of doing so, which at first glance appears more straightforward, as we naturally get a field-theoretic form of the Poisson Brackets and Hamiltonian Mechanics.

Consider some scalar field $\phi:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$. This mapping is a member of the (Banach) vector space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$, which has a natural Hausdorff topology (resulting from the required norm and completeness in a Banach space). Thus, we are able to extend certain theorems from differential geometry to such a field, beginning first with the tangent space. We define $T_f C$, the space tangent to $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$, to be the set of derivations at that point. For this vector space, the set of variational derivatives work nicely. I assume (I still need to prove this) that because the tangent space will be isomorphic to the original space itself, we have the basis:

$$\{\frac{\delta}{\delta f^i}:f^i\in\mathcal{B}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}))\}$$

Where $\frac{\delta}{\delta f}$ is a variational derivative operator and $\mathcal{B}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}))$ is a basis for $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$. Then, we naturally have our space dual to $T_f C$ (denoted by $T^*_fC$), with basis $\{\delta f^i\}$ defined such that $\delta f^i(\frac{\delta}{\delta f^j})=\delta_j^I$. It makes sense to then define the cotangent and tangent bundles (resp.) as:

$$T^*C=\bigsqcup\limits_{f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})}T_f^*C$$

$$TC=\bigsqcup\limits_{f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})}T_fC$$

Thinking of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ as potential functions, it is natural to consider our conjugate momentum fields $\pi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ as behaving such that elements of $\Theta\in T^*C$ are of the form:

$$\Theta=\pi\hspace{.5mm}\delta\phi$$

Where $\delta$ is a variational version of the exterior derivative. Again, I have yet to prove that this works rigorously, but I assume the completeness of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ allows for this one form to make sense. We can then define a two-form $\Omega$ (which must be proven to be non degenerate), allowing us to construct the symplectic manifold $(T^*C,\Omega)$. Note that:

$$\Omega=\delta \pi\wedge\delta\phi$$

From here we define the Hamiltonian vector flow of some functional $F:C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ by:

$$X_F=\frac{\delta F}{\delta \pi}\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi}-\frac{\delta F}{\delta\phi}\frac{\delta}{\delta\pi}$$

And our Poisson Bracket arises naturally as:

$$\{F,G\}=X_F(G)=\Omega(X_F,X_G)=-\{G,F\}$$

From here I imagine one would find some sort of invariant of functionals over the potential and momentum fields and use that to construct an associated (Banach) vector bundle, using the covariant derivative on sections to create a prequantization and ultimately quantization of such functionals. This (according to my intuition) would allow for a quantization on the Fock space $\mathcal{F}$.

My question is whether this methodology is mathematically appropriate. Before I pursue this any further, I want to make sure the underlying logic is sound and whether there are any glaring problems or overcomplications of attempting to formulate second quantization (of bosonic fields) in this way.

Comment: While I can't speak authoritatively on this topic, it's clear to me that the functional analysis is much more involved than what you describe. For instance, $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ is *not* Banach (the standard topology is Fréchet), and indeed the standard formulation of a scalar qauntum field uses a different function space. Depending on your QFT background, you might want to do some reading on the established approaches for navigating these subtleties.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! I will look into those. Would the vector space of (quantum) vector fields  also have the Fréchet topology?

Comment: Also, do you have recommendations for readings concerning the standard approaches? My QFT background consists primarily of SU(2) gluon field theory (my current area of research), and I’ve studied the diff geo / PFB approach to creating such field theories.

Comment: To my knowledge, most introductory QFT texts regard quantum fields as "operator valued distributions", i.e. continuous linear maps from a space of "sufficiently nice" test functions to operators on a Hilbert space (with varying levels of mathematical rigor). For specific references that go into detail on this, I would have to defer to others; [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/551312/what-are-some-good-references-for-field-theory-via-functional-analysis) might have what you're looking for.